# Moving average value at the time when HL was formed

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Struggling to get the Moving average value displayed correctly from the HL candle. Want to see the moving average value @ HL candle

[Script output Screenshot-Please see this also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUWEv.png)

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
Period = 6
smalength = 20
float pivotLow = na
pivotLow := ta.pivotlow(6, 6)
valuewhen_5 = ta.valuewhen(pivotLow, low[Period], 1)
valuewhen_6 = ta.valuewhen(pivotLow, low[Period], 0)
higherlow = na(pivotLow) ? na : valuewhen_5 < valuewhen_6 ? pivotLow : na
plotshape(higherlow, title='HL', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 50), text='HL', textcolor=color.new(color.green, 50), offset=-Period)
plot(ta.sma(close[0], smalength))
var label bbmbcfmlableHL = na
if (not na(higherlow))
    smavalue = ta.valuewhen(higherlow, ta.sma(close, smalength),0)
    bbmbcfmlableHL := label.new(x=bar_index, y=high, color=color.orange,  textcolor=color.blue, text=str.tostring(smavalue))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ignore warnings. You should call the function `ta.sma()` and `ta.valuewhen()` on each bar, and only present the result under the `if` condition.

If you want to present the label on the same bar where the `plotshape` is, you'll need to use the same offset:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
Period = 6
smalength = 20
float pivotLow = na
pivotLow := ta.pivotlow(6, 6)
valuewhen_5 = ta.valuewhen(pivotLow, low[Period], 1)
valuewhen_6 = ta.valuewhen(pivotLow, low[Period], 0)
higherlow = na(pivotLow) ? na : valuewhen_5 < valuewhen_6 ? pivotLow : na
plotshape(higherlow, title='HL', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 50), text='HL', textcolor=color.new(color.green, 50), offset=-Period)

plot(ta.sma(close[0], smalength))
smavalue = ta.valuewhen(higherlow, ta.sma(close, smalength),0)

var label bbmbcfmlableHL = na
if (not na(higherlow))
    bbmbcfmlableHL := label.new(x=bar_index - Period, y=high, color=color.orange,  textcolor=color.blue, text=str.tostring(smavalue))
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It was helpful. Updated my code as below and got the output of what I was expecting. Your help was much appreciated and my gratitude for your advice. Good day.